# Why does adding this line mess up my NHibernate mapping?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a very simple ClassMap

```
public class ContentMap : ClassMap<Content>
{
    public ContentMap()
    {
       // Basic property mapping

       // Parent property mapping
       References(x => x.Category).Column("CategoryId");
    }
}
```

Using this, my mappings work perfectly fine and the `Category` property is not null.

If I try to add this line below the first reference

```
References(x => x.LastActive).Column("LastActiveSubCategoryId");
```

My mappings go wrong.

If `LastActiveSubCategoryId` is null, `Category` maps fine. If it is not null, `LastActiveSubCategoryId` will be set but then `CategoryId` is null.

The actual properties themselves are simple

```
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

public virtual SubCategory LastActive { get; set; }
```

There is nothing complex in the `Category` or `SubCategory` mappings either. They look very similar to the `ContentMap` class (with only one reference line)

Any idea what would cause this behavior? Can I only use one Reference?

**Update**

I've looked at the SQL and this is what appears to be happening, hopefully someone can help me understand why.

The `Content` entity gets inserted into the database just fine with the `CategoryId` and `LastActiveSubCategoryId` null.

The `Category` entity gets inserted and then an update statement updates the `Content`, only updating the `CategoryId` field and nothing else.

If there was no `SubCategory`, everything would be fine at this point.

If there is a `SubCategory`, then a few statements later it is inserted and then the `Category` gets updated. In the update statement a few different values are being modified (some that don't need to be as they haven't changed since the insert), including the `CategoryId` and `SubCategoryId`. Except now `CategoryId` is null and `LastActiveSubCategoryId` is not.

So why would `CategoryId` be null on the update?

**Update 2**

The code I'm using to actually insert the objects is just for some basic tests at this point. These are the relevant bits of code:

```
Category category = new Category();
dao.Save(category);

Content content = new Content();
category.AddContent(content); // Adds it to a list, like in the tutorial mBotros posted
dao.Save(Content);

SubCategory subCategory = new SubCategory();
content.AddSubCategory(subCategory);
dao.Save(subCategory);

// On the Content class
public virtual void AddSubCategory(SubCategory subCategory)
{
   SubCategories.Add(subCategory);
   LastActive = subCategory;
}
```

Comment: i hope this link help
http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping#References_.2F_many-to-one

Comment: It may be helpful to post the code where you create and insert the object into the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a circular reference in your database schema, which can make inserting rows tricky.
`Content` references `SubCategory`, and `SubCategory` references `Content`.  If you were to try to insert rows using plain old SQL, you would *not* be able to do this:

```
/* this line does not work because SubCategory 2 does not exist yet */
insert into Content (Id, LastActiveSubCategoryId) values (1, 2);
insert into SubCategory (Id, ContentId) values (2, 1);
```

You would instead have to do something like this:

```
insert into Content (Id, LastActiveSubCategoryId) values (1, null);
insert into SubCategory (Id, ContentId) values (2, 1);
update Content set LastActiveSubCategoryId = 2 where Id = 1;
```

You need to keep this in mind when you are persisting your NHibernate entities.  Modify `AddSubCategory` to not set `LastActive`.  First save the two entities, then close the loop.

```
// ... code to save Category and Content, then...

SubCategory subCategory = new SubCategory();
content.AddSubCategory(subCategory); // modified to *not* set LastActive
dao.Save(subCategory);

content.LastActive = subCategory;
dao.Update(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention a `LastActiveId` that is not in the code you've shown.

Are you by chance trying to map a column as both a Reference and a scalar Property?

**Update**: either your code snippet is still incomplete, or you're missing the transaction/flush that will cause the updates to happen. Also, do you have both a collection (not shown) called SubCategories *and* a property called LastActive?

Comment: No, sorry. I meant `LastActiveSubCategoryId`

Comment: @Brandon: please post your actual code (the smallest reproduction piece, that is)

Comment: I've updated the question and tried to leave only the important bits.